# syntax error on python 'while' code

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I wrote a code for a guessing game where the user has to guess a number from 1-100. When I tried to run the code on IDLE, I received this message 'EOL while scanning string literal'. Can you help me to overcome this?

Comment: not without seeing the code

Comment: In order to get help with the code you have to include the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This caused by typing in `"some text` and then hit enter without closing the string literal.

Python requires that [`'`/`"` string literals](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html) start and end on the *same* line.

The error message states: "I found an EOL (End of Line) when I was trying to read the end of a single-quoted string!".

Using an editor with syntax highlighting (or including the relevant code in the question) should make the issue quite apparent.